# Eigenvalues, eigenvectors with $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: matrices

Consider the vectorial space defined by $E = (cos (t),sin (t))$.
Consider the following derivation operators defined in $E$ by $D={\frac{d}{dt}} \wedge $$D^2=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$

**a)** Show that $D$ has no eigenvalues in $E$.

**b)** Determine, if possible , the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $E^2$.

Comment: For (a), are there $a,b$ such that $\frac{d}{dt} (a\cos t + b\sin t) = (a\cos t + b\sin t)$?

Comment: For (b), solve $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(a\cos t + b\sin t) = (a\cos t + b\sin t)$ for $a,b$. Hint: $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \cos t = -\cos t$

Comment: There are no eigenvalues because $\frac{d}{dt} (a\cos t + b\sin t) = (a\cos t + b\sin t)$ s always different than zero? I am a bit lost, I cannot even buid a matrix starting with the E vectorial space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M \,: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ is a *linear map* from some vector space $\mathbb{V}$ to itself, and $\mathbb{V}$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$, then $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ is an *eigenvalue* and $0 \neq x  \in \mathbb{V}$ the associated *eigenvector* exactly if $M$ $$
  M(x) = \lambda x \text{.}
$$

In your case, the vector space is over the field $\mathbb{R}$ (I assume, you could also pick $\mathbb{C}$) and contains *functions* - specifically, $$
  \mathbb{V} = \left\{t \mapsto a\cos t + b\cos t \,\big|\, a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \text{,}
$$
and the operations $+ \,: \mathbb{V} \times \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ and $\cdot \,:\, \mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ are defined *point-wise*.

You are looking for eigenvalues of the linear map $$
  D \,: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V} \,:\, f \mapsto \frac{d}{dt}f(t) \text{,}
$$
i.e. for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $f(t) = a\cos t + b\cos t \neq 0$ with $$
  \frac{d}{dt}f = \frac{d}{dt}(a\cos t + b\sin t) = b\cos t - a\sin t = \lambda a\cos t + \lambda b \sin t = \lambda f(t) \text{.}
$$
But that implies $a=b=0$ which contradicts $f \neq 0$, so eigenvalue exists.

---

You can also pick a coordinatization, i.e. treat the vector space as some space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and work things out that way. A natural basis for your vector space is $$
 b_1 = t \mapsto \cos t ,\, b_2 = t \mapsto \sin t \text{.}
$$
To find the matrix representing the operator $D$, you can use that the columns of such a matrix are the images of the basis vectors under $D$, and find $$
  M_D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \text{.}
$$
The eigenvalues are then the zeros of the characteristic polynomial $\det(\lambda I - M_D)$, i.e. of $$
  p(\lambda) = \left|\begin{matrix} \lambda & -1 \\ 1 & \lambda\end{matrix}\right| = \lambda^2 + 1 \text{.}
$$
Since $p$ quite obviously has no (real) zeros, $D$ has no eigenvalues as a linear map on $\mathbb{V}$. Had you picked $\mathbb{C}$ as your field of choice instead of $\mathbb{R}$, however, you *would* find the eigenvalues $\pm i$.